# How can I run a script inside TCP session

Tags: bash, tcp

I want to create a script that uses a couple arguments from the TCP output and prints something back to the TCP input.

I'm trying to solve this with bash, I tried:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/url/port;
msg=$(head -2 <&3)
arg1=$( some grep and sed operation on msg) #is a number
arg2=$( some grep and sed operation on msg) #is a string
counter=0
while [ $counter -lt $arg1 ]
do
    #here I want to print something to netcat input
    echo "$arg2 sometext" >&3;
    ((counter++))
done
#then print the awnser from the server
cat <&3
```

But the script can't write back to netcat input. (No error, ist just does nothing after `echo "$arg2 sometext" >&3` )

Comment: Where is `netcat` in your script? `/dev/tcp != netcat`

Comment: BTW, showing the exact error you get is generally going to lend itself to more useful answers than an English generalization such as "can't write back"; including the specific error answers the question of *why* it can't write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fewer headaches if you avoid `/dev/tcp` and use `socat` to run your code with stdin and stdout connected to the socket.

```
myfunc() {
  local msg msg1 msg2 arg1 arg2 counter
  IFS= read -r msg1 # first line of msg
  IFS= read -r msg2 # second line of msg

  msg="$msg1"$'\n'"$msg2"

  # FYI: There are usually better ways to do string manipulation in bash than grep/sed/etc
  arg1=$(do-something-with "$msg" </dev/null)
  arg2=$(do-something-with "$msg" </dev/null)

  for (( counter=0; counter<arg1; counter++ )); do
    echo "$arg2 sometext"
  done
  cat >&2  # write to stderr, since anything to stdout will go to the remote socket
}
export -f myfunc

socat TCP:"$host":"$port" "SYSTEM:bash -xc myfunc"
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to `echo` to the remote socket, so I replaced `cat >&2` with `cat >&1`. But then the script terminates instantly and I cant get the response from the server.

Comment: `cat >&1` is the same as just `cat`. Stepping back -- why are you writing content the server sends you back to it? Depending on what the server does, that's an easy way to get into an endless loop.

Comment: BTW, if you want to log what's going on, you might replace `cat` with `while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; done` -- it's slower, sure, but since you're running with logs turned on with `bash -xc`, you'll get to see the actual content being processed that way, which is liable to make the issue more obvious.